# Return a pointer to a newed array

Tags: c++, pointers

A pointer to an array is declared as `Type (*p)[N];` . For example,

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int(*ptr_a)[5] = &a;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    cout << (*ptr_a)[i] << endl;
}
```

would ouptut the five integers in `a`.

**How to convert from `new int[5]` to the type `int (*p)[5]`.**

For example, when I write a function that returns a pointer to a new array, the following code doesn't compile.

```
int (*f(int x))[5] {
    int *a = new int[5];
    return a; // Error: return value type does not match the function type.
}
```

It produces:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int (*)[5]’
```

Comment: You can't. There's no array to point to. A pointer is all you get back.

Comment: @Chris yes there is , `new[]` allocates an array, and returns a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Ok, there's no C array object to point to.

Comment: @chris whatever you want to call it, casting `a` to `int(*)[5]` is valid and does what OP wants

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I didn't realize that was a valid cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
int (*a)[5] = new int[1][5];
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int (*a)[5] = new int[1][5];
   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
   {
      (*a)[i] = 10*i;
      std::cout << (*a)[i] << std::endl;
   }
   delete [] a;
}
```

Output:

```
0
10
20
30
40
```

Comment: This is quite clever, until it comes time to delete it :p

Comment: really interesting. Could you explain it in detail how the pointer works here. To me, in essence, a two-dimensional array with just one row 'should be the same' with an one-dimensional array. Thanks.

Comment: `delete[] a;`  . The single `[]` form covers any number of dimensions

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Oh, duh, silly me. It's not a jagged array.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'm not sure the Standard guarantees support for `delete`-ing using a static type with a different number of dimensions to the static type allocated though....

Comment: @TonyD I don't think there is a mismatch, the expression `new int[A][B]` does return `int (*)[B]` , and it's always valid to delete exactly what was new'd

Comment: @MattMcNabb: given "In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.", it's clearly not independent of the type: in this answer the allocated type was `int[1][5]` but the static type known at destruction was `int[5]`, as they differ it's undefined.

Comment: @TonyD Eh? That's like saying `int *t = new int[3]; delete[] t;` is undefined because the allocated type was `int[3]` but the static type is `int`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: yeah - in the end it does boil down to that... my concern's unfounded, at least as long as the static type doesn't misrepresent the least-significant dimension(s) (which can't happen without a cast anyway) and perhaps even then....

Answer (score 4):

You can clean up your code using a `typedef`, then it's easier to see how to get it working:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*P_array_of_5_ints)[5];

P_array_of_5_ints f() {
    int *a = new int[5];
    *a = 42;
    return (P_array_of_5_ints)a;
}

int main()
{
    P_array_of_5_ints p = f();
    std::cout << (*p)[0] << '\n';
}
```

(see it running [here at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/akCQr1))

Comment: preferable (to me, anyway) is to not use a pointer typedef: `typedef int array_of_5_ints[5];` , and then use `array_of_5_ints *` where you have `P_array_of_5_ints`.

Comment: @MattNcNabb: pointer typedefs are most often used when it's anticipated that you might want to substitute some manner of smart pointer later, but otherwise it's much of a muchness (in my opinion)....

Comment: `return (P_array_of_5_ints)a;` That's the root of my confuse. I think the function return should do the conversion just as `(P_array_of_5_ints)a` does. Could you explain why the function return does not do the conversion? Thank you a lot.

Comment: The "`a`" value has type `int*` and there's no implicit conversion from that to `int (*)[5]` (after all, not all `int*` address arrays of 5 `int`s, and many don't address arrays at all).  Hence, you have to force the conversion using a C-style cast or reinterpret cast.  Effectively, `new[]` returns a `int*` because the dimension is allowed to be specified at runtime, so `int*` is a convenient way to represent the set of possible types, which means you've lost the `int (*)[5]` aspect and need to reintroduce it.

Answer (score 1):

You have this tagged C++ so please just don't do this. Use `vector` instead. It cleans up the whole syntax *and* makes sure you don't leak memory!

```
std::vector<int> f(int x)
{
    std::vector<int> a(5);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Well. I am learning the how pointer works in C++. I know vector and array, etc. I am just confused about the conversion when I tried to do an exercise in C++ primer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int (*f(int x))[5]
{
    int (*a)[5] = new int[1][5];
    return a; // Error: return value type does not match the function type.
}


int main(void)
{

 int a[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
 int(*ptr_a)[5] = &a;
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
 {
    cout << (*ptr_a)[i] << endl;
    cout << f(i) << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11 have a better way of dealing with fixed sized arrays. I recommend to use std::array instead of c-style arrays. A modern compiler should emit equal efficent code, than the pointer version.

```
std::array<int,5> f()
{
    std::array<int,5> a;
    return a; 
}
```

If you really want to mess with pointers, use the following.

```
std::array<int,5>* f()
{
    std::array<int,5>* a = new std::array<int,5>;
    return a; 
}
```

I additionally recommend to not use raw pointers but smart pointers (eg. std::unique_ptr), to prevent memory leaks by forgetting to delete the array.

```
typedef std::array<int,5> array_of_5_ints;
std::unique_ptr<array_of_5_ints> f()
{
    std::unique_ptr<array_of_5_ints> a = new std::array<int,5>;
    return a; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your function to

```
int (*f())[5] {
    int *a = new int[5];
    //code ...
    return (int (*)[5])a;
}
```